# Terminal INSERT into MySQL Not Working

Tags: mysql, terminal

I im creating mysql script that creates database, tables and insert data into created table...but i need to do it using ubuntu terminal..i successfully created database and tables but my INSERT sql statement does not insert nothing into table...

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE "mydatabase"" | mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD; \
echo "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "servers";" | mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD mydatabase; \   
echo "CREATE TABLE "servers" ( \
    "id" int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \
    "server" varchar(64) NOT NULL, \
    "ip" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, \
    "panel" int(4) NOT NULL, \
    PRIMARY KEY ("id") \
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;" | mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD mydatabase; \
    echo "LOCK TABLES "servers" WRITE;" | mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD mydatabase; \
```

This code above works and creates database and tables and next command does not insert into table from terminal and i could not find any errors...so why is not inserting into table?

```
echo "INSERT INTO servers (id, server, ip, panel) VALUES (1, \''+rows[0].server+'\', \'INET_ATON('+rows[0].ip+')\', '+rows[0].panel+');" | mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD mydatabase; \
echo "UNLOCK TABLES;" | mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD mydatabase;
```

Comment: May I ask why you are piping text commands into MySQL instead of logging in directly to the command line tool?  I don't have your issues when I use the command line tool from my Mac.

Comment: i im making portable node js apk that executest all in terminal so that i have one js file and make it portable..i don't want to use multiple files for instalation and sql dump file...so this is why i need to do it using terminal

Comment: My first guess is that the insert statement has some sort of escaping problem.  What do you see when you let the `echo` go to the terminal output directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should try your `echo "INSERT…"` without the `| mysql` to see what it outputs.

Typically the one you wrote in your question:

```
echo "INSERT INTO servers (id, server, ip, panel) VALUES (1, \''+rows[0].server+'\', \'INET_ATON('+rows[0].ip+')\', '+rows[0].panel+');" | mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD mydatabase; \
```

without its `| mysql` outputs:

```
INSERT INTO servers (id, server, ip, panel) VALUES (1, \''+rows[0].server+'\', \'INET_ATON('+rows[0].ip+')\', '+rows[0].panel+');
```

You can now try to evaluate this in your brain or copy and paste it to a MySQL to see what happend. I am personally now able to interpret it in my brain, it yields "Syntax error near '\''+rows[0].server+'\''".

I don't know where your `rows` come from, but `rows[0].ip` in bash is not a legal syntax, are you mixing languages? It won't work.

Side note, you should use here documents instead of lots of backslash, it will be more readable:

```
cat <<EOF | mysql …
   CREATE TABLE "servers" (
    "id" int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    "server" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    "ip" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    "panel" int(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
EOF
```

Comment: thanks i get error ERROR 1366 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect integer value: 'INET_ATON(192.168.28.32)' for column 'ip' at row 1 so i now fix it and now is working..thanks for tip for debugging